# Debug Assertion Failed in mfc140ud

Tags: sockets, debugging, mfc, assertion

I use vs2015. When I run my program in debug mode this debug assertion failed happend.

[image]

Anyone knows how to deal with it?

Release mode is OK.

Comment: Do as suggested in the dialog, that is press Retry. This will show the MFC source code where the problem happens and this will give you valuable information about what could be wrong.

Comment: There's a bug in your code, code we cannot see. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replys. I think the mainly reason is the socket workthread sendmessage to close the socket itself in a multi-thread application.